# I want to insert a new column in pandas followed with some sort of grouping condition

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pLHl.png)
I want to add a column for duration which subtracts max date from min date for each company(ComapnyName)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
m1 = df.groupby('CompanyName')['Date'].transform('max')
m2 = df.groupby('CompanyName')['Date'].transform('min')
df['duration'] = (m1 - m2).dt.days
```